# javascript regex does not work properly with postal code

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

```
'^[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]{1}\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}[ -]*\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}\d{1}$'
```

the above regular expression accepts inputs like T3K2H3 or T3K-2H3 from .net form but when i run the validation through the javascript; it does not work.

```
var rxPostalCode = new RegExp('^[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]{1}\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}[ -]*\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}\d{1}$');

var postalCode = 't3k2h3';

var matchesPostalCode = rxPostalCode.exec(postalCode);

if (matchesPostalCode == null || postalCode != matchesPostalCode[0]) {

    $scope.AccountInfoForm.PostalCode.$setValidity("pattern", false);

    $scope.showLoading = false;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: according to online regex validator your regex should match, see http://regex101.com/r/zN7iX0

Comment: @donfuxx, I changed my answer to address another problem which I think is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in javascript, you have to do `//` instead of `''`

as follows:

`/^[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]{1}\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}[ -]*\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}\d{1}$/`

You might want to check the following link:

[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: This does not respect the classes defined in OP's question

Comment: seems like that is not what is wanted, because seems like letters like `d` `q` etc are not wanted. Also the part: `[ -]` looks like should be optional

Comment: @donfuxx, Thank you, I will make those changes

Comment: Well, `[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]` is not the same thing as `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntaxes to define a regexp object:

```
var rxPostalCode = /^[abceghj-np-tvxy]\d[abceghj-np-tv-z][ -]?\d[abceghj-np-tv-z]\d$/i;
```

or

```
var rxPostalCode = new RegExp('^[abceghj-np-tvxy]\\d[abceghj-np-tv-z][ -]?\\d[abceghj-np-tv-z]\\d$',  'i');
```

Note that with the second syntax you need to use double backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
^[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]\d
[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz][ -]*\d
[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]\d
```

Remove the $ at the end and see if that solves your problem.

I also simplified things a bit, the `\d{1}` is the same as `\d`

I would also change the `[ -]*` to `[ -]?` unless you want to allow multiple spaces or dashes

I suspect what is happening is that the $ expect the end of the line or string, and JavaScript may not store the VAR properly.   See if remove the $ solves it, or possibly keeping the $ and trim() the string.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

"Do not forget to escape \ itself while using the RegExp("pattern") notation because \ is also an escape character in strings."

```
var rxPostalCode = new RegExp('^[AaBbCcEeGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvXxYy]{1}\\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}[ -]*\\d{1}[AaBbCcEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnPpRrSsTtVvWwXxYyZz]{1}\\d{1}$');
```

That should work, I tested it in Chrome's console.